# Set an object reference to null in javascript, would the object be garbage collected

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I have two scenarios, will they both get garbage collected?  Scenario one, it is a function object, and second scenario, it is an object.

```
// Scenario one
function ListNode (val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
}

var nodeA = new ListNode(1);
var nodeB = new ListNode(2);
var nodeC = new ListNode(3);

// connect A, B, C
nodeA.next = nodeB;
nodeB.next = nodeC;
// skip B
nodeA.next = nodeC;
// now B's next is still pointing to nodeC
// I want to remove B and let garbage collector collects
// B, will setting B's reference to null work?

nodeB = null;

// Scenario two
var obj = {a: 123, b: 456};
// this obj will be garbage collected if I set the ref to null?
obj = null;
```

Comment: Objects are garbage-collected some time after they have no references.  Period.

Comment: Yes, both things work, but in the first scenario you should consider pooling the nodes.